# Beginner Eagle PCB design - Switch with double outputs

Tags: pcb, switches, eaglecad

I'm designing a double-sided PCB that requires a switch with double connectors to switch two different parts of the circuit. The two sides of the switch are used to switch resistors on an eFuse and a DC-DC module to produce 12 or 5 V.

Is there a way to have a switch with 6 pins on the PCB to connect to two "normal" (one in, two out) switches in the schematic, or is this made manually in the PCB design phase?

EDIT:
DPDT Switch in question
[image: This is what i'm hoping for in the schematic with a single component in board -view]

Comment: It will be easier to understand your question if you draw a diagram. See this for common switches: https://www.moujenglobal.com/post/what-does-spst-spdt-dpst-and-dpdt-mean

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand the question. Have you used the component editor (Library)? You can draw any component you like.

Comment: The component you are looking for is a "DPDT" (Double pole, double throw) switch.  I don't use Eagle, but I would expect to find a DPDT switch in the standard schematic libraries, but you may have to create a footprint to match the switch you have.  If a DPDT switch does not exist in the schematic library, it should be easy to create a suitable schematic symbol.  Creating your own schematic symbols and footprints is a common task in electronic design.

Comment: Seems now that what I was looking for was to have multiple symbols for a single component in a Eagle library which is a basic function of the program. Thanks for your answers and questions that helped me solve this.